# Status Code 0 error for api call between 2 app registration within same tenant in azure

Tags: authorization, http-status-codes

I have a api call from one app registration to another in one of my project
i was able to successfully call the api in pre-prod
but in prod it's showing status 0 as response
http status code 0 is very strange and not able to resolve it
can anyone please help to give a broad idea about http status code 0

i was expecting a status code of 200 but the response was 0